# What can we use as sources of inspiration for questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am already starting to have trouble coming up with good questions for the site. At least in chat I have seen other users have a similar sentiment as well. Sure there are time constraints in people's lives but it is not up to a small number of individuals to keep the site alive. Also I am sure the site is going to lose momentum at some point.

Therefore I think It would be good to have a list of sources of inspiration and concepts that people can refer to if they want to contribute good questions but lack the ideas or experience they need to form them in order to maintain a healthy stream of questions.

Comment: I know "copying" isn't the cool thing to do, nor should we.  Ravelry is a place where many Fiber Arts & Crafts folks are drawn to.. at times like to a bug zapper... bzzzzt, no wings.  I would hope this space becomes a "higher level" than Ravelry, Something has to!  IMHO   JLH

Comment: You can also have contests to ask questions, similar to world building.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That would be a good idea worth visiting when we get a larger user base. I like it.

Answer (score 5):

This comes in part from a [similar thread on Meta Woodworking.SE](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-can-we-maintain-a-healthy-number-of-questions). Many of the solutions there are general enough they can apply here.

- Consider mistakes you have made in the past. Perhaps you would like to know how that could have been avoided or mitigated.

Those would be good but not limited to [safety](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) questions.

- Consider questions friends and family have asked you while they watched you work. Others would likely share these same questions.
- Perhaps you are an active member in other arts and craft sites (specialized or not). You can reask those questions here as well to give them exposure to another audience.
- Look at all the tools of your craft or crafts, and for each one ask yourself the following questions:

  1. What problems have I had with this tool?
  2. What do I know now that I wish I would have known before?
  3. Why did I buy this tool?
  4. Do I still use this tool? Why or why not?
  5. Am I using this tool in the most efficient way possible?

Those could be good [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) questions.

- Consider tools that you don't own but have considered buying, and ask yourself the following questions:

  1. Why do I think I want that tool?
  2. Why haven't I bought that type of tool yet?
  3. What would I want to know before I would ever buy it?

Those could be good [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) questions.

- Consider if the question can be split into more that one. Often when asking questions we naturally have others that are related. If those other questions could justify their own answers then perhaps they deserve their own questions.
- Plenty of crafting YouTube (and other tutorial medium) videos out there. Perhaps you wanted to know exactly how something was done? Perhaps you want a critique of something you saw?
- Perhaps you are considering starting a craft you are not familiar with and have questions? Be careful with this one as to not be too broad of opinionated. Be as specific as you can and don't forget you can always ask more than one question.

Comment: Oh my yes, there are (including Pa in his workshop) Hundreds of Spinning Wheel builders.  There are Less in the home fiber processing tools. Washing, Drying, Dyeing, Picking, Carding, Spinning, Knitting tool types.  Then you step into the warm pile of Weaving.  Oh my, Loom Manufacturers, Accessories, bobbin winders, cone holders, software, expandability, computer interface, ... on it goes...  Then those folks that buy "real mills" in the small mill "home garage" full commercial industrial type.

Comment: Not just youtube, but Make, and Instructables have become part of the youtube counter culture, when it is getting information to the masses.

Comment: @JoelHuebner yes. There are definitely many forms on tuts on the webs these days.